# I want to search for one or multiple words in a search bar

Tags: php, sql, pdo

My query always works when I enter 1 word, but when I enter multiple words, the query is weird. It misses some video in the same categories and get some videos that are not in the same categories. I bet it has to do whit the "AND" & "OR" in the query but im not sure.

Here is my code.

```
if(isset($_GET['search']) AND !empty($_GET['search']) AND $_GET['search'] != ' ') {
    $search = htmlspecialchars($_GET['search']);
    $searchArray = explode(' ',$search);

    $videos = $stdb->prepare('SELECT id, title, videoTime FROM videos WHERE categories LIKE "skateboard" AND title LIKE "%'.implode("\" OR title LIKE \"%", $searchArray).'%" ORDER BY id DESC limit '.$start.','.$videosPerPage);
    $videos->execute();

    $totalVideosReq = $stdb->prepare('SELECT id FROM videos WHERE categories LIKE "snowboard" AND title LIKE "%'.implode("\" OR title LIKE \"%", $searchArray).'%" ORDER BY id DESC');
    $totalVideosReq->execute();
    $totalVideos = $totalVideosReq->rowcount();
    var_dump($totalVideos);
    $totalPages = ceil($totalVideos/$videosPerPage);

    $currentPage = 1;
    if(isset($_GET['page']) AND !empty($_GET['page']) AND $_GET['page'] > 0 AND $_GET['page'] <= $totalPages) {
        $_GET['page'] = intval($_GET['page']);
        $currentPage = $_GET['page'];
    } else {
        $currentPage = 1;
    }
}
```

Does someone know if, since `$searchArray` is the `explode()` of `$search`, the query is secure from SQL injection?

Comment: No, explode of `$search` will not prevent SQL injections, but would be more difficult due to exploding on spaces. Better method would be to utilize `rtrim(str_repeat('title LIKE ? OR ', count($searchArray)), ' OR ');` Then `bindValues` on the placeholders or add to a `$parameters` array to pass to prepared statement's `execute()` https://3v4l.org/p8Rpg

Comment: If i do : `$videos->bindParam(':searchArray', $searchArray);` and replace $searchArray whit :searchArray in the query would be ok ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue of preference is due to the way `OR` functions, which results in.

```
if ($category == 'snowboard' AND $title == 'first_string') {
  record
} elseif ($title == 'second_string') {
  record
} ... etc
```

Allowing for you to do separate conditions like:

```
category = 'snowbord' AND title = 'first_string' 
OR 
category = 'ski' AND title = 'second_string'
```

In order to apply the category to all of the titles searched for, you need to wrap the `OR`'s in parentheses `()` similar to in PHP if conditions.

---

To answer your question in the comment; while using `bindParam` or `execute($parameters)` would provide a more secure query. You can not pass either an array of values for a placeholder value.

eg: `bindParam(':searchArray', ['Hello', 'World'])` would not work.

You would need a separate placeholder and parameter for each `LIKE '%search_string%'` that is desired.

```
$search = "Hello World";
$searchArray = explode(' ', $search);

//create a like condition for each search word
$likes = rtrim(str_repeat('title LIKE ? OR ', count($searchArray)), ' OR ');

//surround each search word with '%' to find strings containing the word
$parameters = array_map(function($value) { return '%' . $value . '%'; }, $searchArray);

$query = 'SELECT id, title, videoTime 
    FROM videos 
    WHERE categories LIKE "skateboard" 
    AND (' . $likes . ')
    ORDER BY id DESC 
    LIMIT '. $start . ',' . $videosPerPage;

$videos = $stdb->prepare($query);
$videos->execute($parameters);
var_dump($query);
var_dump($parameters);
```

Results: https://3v4l.org/YG8Jo

```
#query
string(141) "SELECT id, title, videoTime 
FROM videos 
WHERE categories LIKE "skateboard" 
AND (title LIKE ? OR title LIKE ?)
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 1,20"

#parameters
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "%Hello%"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "%World%"
}
```

See:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#example-1034 for
  more details on using parameters and placeholders.
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html
  for general information on prepared statements

---

Additionally, for your second query, I would change to read.

```
$query = 'SELECT COUNT(id)
    FROM videos 
    WHERE categories LIKE "snowboard" 
    AND ('. $likes .')';

$totalVideosReq = $stdb->prepare($query);
$totalVideosReq->execute($parameters);
$totalVideos = $stdb->fetchColumn();
var_dump($totalVideos);
$totalPages = ceil($totalVideos/$videosPerPage);
```

`ORDER BY` will slow down the query, and you do not need to return the rows from the database to count, since MySQL can do that for you.

See http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php#example-1049 for reference on `rowCount` and it's usage with `SELECT` statements.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Was a great help and really detailed. The only thing is i dont really understand how the `$parameters` or the `$likes` protect my query from SQL injection.For the second query, after removing the useless `ORDER BY desc`, is it better to use: `SELECT COUNT(id)` whit `$totalVideos = $stdb->fetchColumn();` or `SELECT id` whit `$totalVideos = $totalVideosReq->rowcount();`? does its make a difference ?

Comment: SQL Injection occurs by people manipulating the form fields to run malicious queries due to accepting the received value directly in your SQL statement. The `$parameters` tells the SQL Server that they are not to be run as `SQL` but instead as escaped string values at the positions of the placeholders. There are methods an exploiter would use, such as special character escaping, and others that make it possible to circumvent things like `explode`, `add_slashes`, `htmlentities` and `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please upvote it, or mark it as accepted if it resolved your issue so that others know that your question has been answered.

Comment: With `rowCount`, you're issuing a second query to the server, for it to report the affected rows from the last executed query and the results are not always accurate when used with `SELECT`.  It is best to reserve its use for `UPDATE`, `INSERT` or `DELETE` statements to retrieve the number of affected records. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php#example-1049 Where issuing a single `COUNT` query will be much faster and achieve the same results accurately.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing a closing % to wrap around the LIKE. I think you are after:

```
$stdb->prepare('SELECT id FROM videos WHERE categories LIKE "snowboard" AND title LIKE "%'.implode("%\" OR title LIKE \"%", $searchArray).'%" ORDER BY id DESC');
```

Comment: it does the same thing whit the "%" but if i do the query whitout `WHERE categories LIKE "snowboard"` it work . When i enter more than 1 word in the search bar it add more "OR title LIKE " in the query and the 'WHERE categories LIKE "skateboard" ' lose is priority but i dont know why !

Comment: Can you post the full query? That might help.